# Adding a Role to an IdentityUser .net core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

I have a set of API's that I want to put some authentication on.  I have added the authorization and authentication pieces to the project.  I have added the context for the database and the application user.  I can create users and log them and in and return JWT to the caller and validate the users based on the JWT.  However, there are certain users that I want to create that are admins that will have elevated privileges. Here is the code I am user to Create a user:

```
async Task<Response> ICreateUser.CreateUser(RegisterModel model)
    {
        var userExists = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
        if (userExists != null)
        {
            return  new Response { Status = "error", Message = "User already exists" };
        }
        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            Email = model.Email,
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            UserName = model.UserName

        };
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "Unable to create user" };
        }
        else
        {
            var adminRole = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("admin");
            if(!await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, adminRole.Name))
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, adminRole.Name);
            }
           

        }
        return new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "User Created" };
    }
```

This will add the user, and even add them to the role.  But when I do a list on the claims all I see are the nameidentifier, jti, email, exp, iss, and aud values.  Here is the code I am using to return the claims:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {

        

        var claims = User.Claims.Select(claim => new { claim.Type, claim.Value }).ToArray();
        return Json(claims);
    }
```

When I created the Role for the admin I used this code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Required] string name)
    {
        var adminRole = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(name);
        if (adminRole == null)
        {
            adminRole = new IdentityRole(name);
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(adminRole);
            await roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, name));

            return Ok("Role Created");
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "error", Message = "Role Not created" });
        }
    }
```

Like I said, I can create the user, but I don't see the Admin claim added to user so I can't authenticate by the role.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When I created the JWT token I needed to add a call to GetRolesAsync.  Once I got this list, I could loop through the array and add the claims.

```
 var claim = new List<Claim>();
            claim.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName));
            claim.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
            claim.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, model.Email));

            var roles = userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.ToArray();
            foreach(var role in roles)
            {
                claim.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
            }
```

This bit of code allows me to add the user to the roles they are assigned to when they are created.